# Run os.system() multiple times simultaneously in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I've written the following short python script to download flv videos using cclive on a Fedora 17 system.

```
urls = [line.strip() for line in open("urls.txt")]
for url in urlstoget:
    os.system('cclive %s' % url)
```

It works fine but the videos are limited to about 80kbps. I have a 39 to download and would like to download 2-4 simultaneously.

How can I run the os.system() command multiple times simultaneously?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use either `threading` or `multiprocessing`.

Here's an example using multiprocessing:

```
def retrieve_url(url):
    os.system('cclive %s' % url)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
pool.map(retrieve_url, list_of_urls)
```

And a link to another SO question:  [Python - parallel commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12097406/748858)

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. Well the screen output progress bars are all stacked on top of each other at the bottom of the screen from cclive but its running 4 times. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the subprocess module, the Popen() method in particular. You could also use os.fork()

Comment: subprocess is an excellent solution here (In some ways better than my answer).  I don't know why I didn't think of it ...

Comment: Thanks I looked at subprocess but I've only been programming a couple of months and docs.python is as cryptic as ever.

Comment: @James -- you'll get used to the format of the docs if you stick with it.  They're actually quite easy to read/use once you get the hang of it.