# Simple way to restart application

Tags: python, linux

Some library has some memory leak, and as a simple solution, I just want to restart my script frequently. My script does some long calculation but I can just save the state and then load it again, so restarting it is not a problem.

For restarting, I was just using `os.execv`:

```py
os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable] + sys.argv)
```

However, now after a while, I get `Too many open files`.

Why is that? As far as I know, all file descriptors (fds) should have been closed after `exec`? I thought we always have the close-on-exec flag set? But maybe not? Or maybe not for all the libraries? Maybe I misunderstood the documentation. Can someone clarify this?

How would I close all fds before the `exec`? `os.closerange`? Maybe just:

```py
max_fd = os.sysconf("SC_OPEN_MAX")
os.closerange(3, max_fd)
os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable] + sys.argv)
```

Does that work correctly then?

What are other simple solutions of restarting? I assume fork+exec+exit will just have the same problem then? Or spawn+exit?

Comment: How are you invoking `os.execv`?

Comment: @MarioCamilleri Just directly? I extended the question. But maybe I did not understand your question.

Comment: `exec` does not close any file descriptors.

Comment: `while True: subprocess.run()`?

Comment: @tripleee Not? I thought we always have close-on-exec flag set?

Comment: Did any of those questions with same error-message compare or help to yours? [multiprocessing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67365870/too-many-open-files-error-with-python-multiprocessing), [subprocess in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526783/python-subprocess-too-many-open-files)

Comment: @hc_dev No I'm not creating a new subprocess here. I just want to restart the app. I ask why `exec` does not work, and how to solve that, or what are other simple solutions.

Comment: Which operating system are you using this in? E.g. in a [Python issue 19123](https://bugs.python.org/issue19124) some suggests using `subprocessPopen` or `spawnv` instead `execv`.

Comment: @hc_dev `spawnv` would spawn a new subprocess which I don't need. Or do you suggest I should use spawnv + exit?

Comment: Well a chance to get a pid or file-object as return, like in `spawnv` or `popen`, would allow to close or `_exit(n)` it.

Comment: @hc_dev I don't exactly understand your comment. Maybe you can put it into an answer? Or is this actually related to my question (how to restart my script)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.execv` does not by itself close any file descriptors. (Think about it: If the `exec` system call closed file descriptors, there would be no way for the standard fork+exec model to pass on standard input, standard output, and standard error to new processes.) The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execv) implicitly mentions this, as it explains that you need to `flush` any data on any open file handles before calling `os.execv`.

Like you describe, [PEP-446](https://peps.python.org/pep-0446/) implemented close-on-exec for *most* file descriptors created by Python itself. Without access to your code, we can only infer that some of the file descriptors your code creates are outside the scope of the PEP (or created by `os.dup2()`, where you can control the behavior, but the default is to make the file descriptors inheritable).

Your `os.closerange` code should work for what you are asking. If you wanted to be more precise, [check what files are open in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023608/check-what-files-are-open-in-python) has ideas for how to find out which files are open (which could be useful for troubleshooting the root cause, even if you end up using the `closerange` solution to remediate the immediate problem).

Comment: Yes, right, it does not make sense that exec closes all file descriptors. But it closes all those with this flag, right? Is this done by Linux, or by Python? In case of fork+exec or spawn, how is the situation then? Does fork closes any fds? Does spawn inherit fds? I guess I should fix some of my own fork+exec code in various projects where I never cared about fds. I guess you always must have an explicit `closerange` then in there, right?

Comment: The OS closes any file descriptors on `exec` which were marked as close-on-exec when you created them. Dunno about `spawn`; my impression is that it's only useful on Windows really.

Comment: As for explicit `closerange`, that would only really make sense in long-running processes where you can't otherwise ensure that you don't leak file handles. More of a band-aid, then, than what I would consider recommended practice.